# Find dependencies for a static library on Mac OS X

Tags: ios, macos, dependencies, static-libraries

I'm on Mac OS X 10.10.5

I use XCode 7.0 to build an enterprise iOS app for work.

Some of the libraries in this enterprise app are static and some are dynamic.

I've been able to use `otool -L` to tell me exactly what i need for ***dynamic libraries***, but **static libraries** I just get a list of .o files that went into building the static library, and that doesn't tell me anything about what the dependencies are.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `otool -l` with a lowercase l?

Comment: @chedabob Yes, that spits out a bunch of crazy gibberish that would be useful to someone working in assembly or something.